# Is there any non-trivial library for reducing boilerplate in Django CRUD apps?

Tags: python, django, crud, web2py

I've been working with web2py during the last time, but for my new web application I want to experiment with Django. However, I've found that trivial CRUD forms require a lot of boilerplate. I understand that generic views give me all the logic for input to or output from a model, but I still have to do heavy HTML work and add my own logic to support filters, ordering, pagination, etc.

For example, in web2py I can just use the following code (consider it as the function-based view in Django's world) to get a feature-rich and highly-customizable CRUD view.

```
def manage_users():
    grid = SQLFORM.grid(db.users)
    return {"grid": grid}
```

[image]

Is there any de-facto way (apart from the admin application) or library you Django folks use to reduce the boilterplate of writing ~200 lines of code to achieve the same thing that web2py gives you for free?

Note: this is not a web2py vs. Django question. I understand they propose different philosophies and that Django is much more flexible than web2py, while web2py gives you more features out of the box. I'm just asking how is this resolved in the Django world.

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Not sure why you have excluded that but I believe the equivalent functionality in Django world is the admin application. There are also 3rd party packages you can check out at https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/tables/

Comment: Additionally, if you are looking to reduce boilerplate for CRUD endpoints (like a REST API) it's worth looking at DRF http://django-rest-framework.org/

Comment: @Selcuk Ok it seems like the [`django-tables2`](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package might be a good choice.